# Is it possible to disable Firebase's auto-conversion to native arrays?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

In the Firebase documentation, it says:

> Firebase stores all data as Objects, even Arrays are stored as objects with numerical keys.
>   As a convenience, the Firebase Web API automatically converts Array-like Objects into Arrays
>   for use JavaScript.

This "convenience" is a royal pain, in my opinion. Is there any way to disable the automatic conversion, while still using array-like objects with numerical keys? I am using the [arrayjs](http://matthewmueller.github.io/array/) library, and would like to maintain those array-like objects throughout the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also says in the docs:  "It's not currently possible to change or prevent this behavior." So no, you can't disable it.

You can work around it as follows:

- add any non-numeric key to the path (e.g. "ignoreme": true), which will prevent any keys from being treated as numeric
- prefix the item keys with a string (e.g. "rec1", "rec2"...)
- make the numbers non-consecutive

But in reality, sequential numeric ids in distributed real-time data [are ill advised](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and should be avoided for most cases. They cause nothing but heartache.